# Cant connect to database, no errors displayed

Tags: php, html, database, database-connection

I'm building a website where students can submit their projects. However, the process_submission.php file isn't working as expected. It's not showing any success or failure messages, and it's not saving the form details to the database. Can you help me fix this?

Using the same db_connection.php file, im able to connect to the relevant database for signup/login.

I've reviewed the file path, permissions, and added error logs, but there's still no indication of errors or success. However, for the signup/login functionality, it does show success or failure to connect to the databases and inserts into the database as intended.
The relevant files have been included above, any advice would be appreciated!

student_dash.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Student Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
   <!-- Student Submission Section -->
   <section class="student-submission">
    <h2>Make a Submission</h2>

    <!-- Main Submission Form -->
    <!-- enctype for file inputs, included name attributes -->
    <form id="mainSubmissionForm" action="process_submission.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
        <label for="projectName">Project Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="projectName" name="projectName" required placeholder="Enter the project name">
    
        <label for="projectSummary">Project Summary:</label>
        <textarea id="projectSummary" name="projectSummary" required placeholder="Enter a brief summary of the project"></textarea>
    
        <label for="projectDetails">Project Details:</label>
        <textarea id="projectDetails" name="projectDetails" required placeholder="Enter detailed information about the project"></textarea>
     
        <label for="projectField">Project Field:</label>
        <select id="projectField" name="projectField" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Project Field</option>
            <option value="field1">Field 1</option>
            <option value="field2">Field 2</option>
        </select>
        
        <label for="projectYear">Project Year:</label>
        <select id="projectYear" name="projectYear" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Project Year</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
            <option value="2023">2023</option>
        </select>
    
        <!-- File input for video -->
        <label for="videoUpload">Video Upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="videoUpload" name="videoUpload" accept="video/*">
    
        <!-- File input for image -->
        <label for="imageUpload">Image Upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="imageUpload" accept="image/*">
    
        <div class="checkbox-section">
            <input type="checkbox" id="includeAuthorDetails" name="includeAuthorDetails">
            <label for="includeAuthorDetails">Include Author's Details</label>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Author Details Form, hide by default -->
        <div class="author-details-form" id="authorDetailsForm" style="display: none;">
            <label for="authorFirstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="authorFirstName" name="authorFirstName" placeholder="Enter Your First Name">
            <br>
            <label for="authorLastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="authorLastName" name="authorLastName" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name">
            <br>
            <label for="authorEmail">Your Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="authorEmail" name="authorEmail" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
        </div>
        <!-- Submit Button for Main Submission Form -->
        <button type="submit">Submit Project</button>
    </form>
    
</section>

    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <script defer src="ajaxScript.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

process_submission.php:

```
<?php
// Include the database connection file
include '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/db_connection.php';

// Initialise error flag
$errorFlag = false;

// Check if the form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Retrieve form data
    $projectName = $_POST["projectName"];
    $projectSummary = $_POST["projectSummary"];
    $projectDetails = $_POST["projectDetails"];
    $projectField = $_POST["projectField"];
    $projectYear = $_POST["projectYear"];
    $videoUpload = $_FILES["videoUpload"]["name"];
    $imageUpload = $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"];
    $authorFirstName = isset($_POST["authorFirstName"]) ? $_POST["authorFirstName"] : "";
    $authorLastName = isset($_POST["authorLastName"]) ? $_POST["authorLastName"] : "";
    $authorEmail = isset($_POST["authorEmail"]) ? $_POST["authorEmail"] : "";

    // Upload files
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["videoUpload"]["tmp_name"], $targetDir . $videoUpload);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"], $targetDir . $imageUpload);

    try {
        // Prepare SQL statement
        $query = "INSERT INTO projects (projectName, projectSummary, projectDetails, projectField, projectYear, videoUpload, imageUpload, authorFirstName, authorLastName, authorEmail) 
                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

        if ($stmt) {
            // Bind parameters to prepared statement
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $projectName, $projectSummary, $projectDetails, $projectField, $projectYear, $videoUpload, $imageUpload, $authorFirstName, $authorLastName, $authorEmail);

            // Execute the prepared statement
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: Execution failed";
            }

            // Close the statement
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Failed to prepare the SQL statement.");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

signup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="signupForm" action="process_signup.php" method="POST">
        <h2>New Here?</h2>
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <div class="textBoxdiv">
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="textBoxdiv">
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="textBoxdiv">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="textBoxdiv">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required> 
            <!-- hide criteria as default -->
            <p id="passwordCriteria" class="criteriaMessage" style="display: none;">Password must: <br> Be at least 8 characters  <br> And include: <br> 1 letter <br>  1 number <br> 1 special character</p>
        </div>        
        <button type="submit" class="signupBtn">Sign Up</button>
        <div class="login">
            <h3>Already have an account?</h3>
        <h3><a href="login.php">Login</a></h3>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <script defer src="ajaxScript.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

process_signup.php:`<?php

```
<?php
// Include the database connection file
include 'db_connection.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Check if the form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Retrieve form data
    $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Hash the password

    // Insert user data into the 'users' table
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    // try-catch block to handle any potential exceptions
    try {
        $connAuthentication = connectToDatabase("user_authentication"); 
        $stmt = $connAuthentication->prepare($query); 

        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $password);

            // Check if the insertion was successful
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                // Registration successful
                $response = array(
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'message' => 'Registration successful!',
                );

                // Redirect based on user role
                $userId = $stmt->insert_id; 
                $redirectUrl = determineRedirectUrl($userId);
                header("Location: $redirectUrl");
                exit(); // Ensure script stops after redirection
            } else {
                // Registration failed
                $response = array(
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'Registration failed. Please try again.',
                );
            }

            // Close the database 
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Failed to prepare the SQL statement.");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle exceptions, log the error, or display an appropriate message
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'An error occurred. Please try again later.',
        );
    }


    // Send JSON response
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // Invalid request
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Invalid request.";
}

// Function to determine the appropriate dashboard based on user role
function determineRedirectUrl($userId) {
    $isStudent = true; 
    if ($isStudent) {
        return 'student_dash.html';
    } else {
        return 'lecturers_dash.html';
    }
}
?>
```

db_connection.php file

```
<?php
/// Function to create a database connection
function connectToDatabase($databaseName) {
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "my_user";
    $password = "my_pass";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $conn->set_charset("utf8");

    // Temporary logging
    error_log("Connection successful to database: $databaseName");
    // Avoid echoing here, it can cause issues with JSON responses or HTML output
    // echo "Connection successful to database: $databaseName"; 

    return $conn;
}

// Connect to project_database
$connProject = connectToDatabase("project_submission");

// Connect to user_authentication database
$connAuthentication = connectToDatabase("user_authentication");

session_start();

?>
```

Comment: How far through the code does it get, when you debug it?

Comment: Why do you connect to the database a second time? Your `db_connection` include file makes two connections, and then your individual processing pages connect again.

Comment: Your form executes `process_uploads.php`, but you've shown us `process_submission.php` - is that a typo on the post, or an actual error? As there's a similar discrepancy in the between the signup html and the name you've shown for the processing code, I suspect it's just a typo.

Comment: Sorry both were typos, ive now corrected- thank you. Nothing shows up in php_error.log. Ive created a test file to test the connection and that works fine so i dont believe theres an error with privileges or pathname. @droopsnoot

Comment: So, starting adding some `echo` and `var_dump()` statements throughout your processing code to see how far through it's getting. Basic debugging steps - look at the values of the variables your code is receiving. If it's getting as far as the query, try running the query with the same values inside phpmyadmin and see if you get an error message.

Comment: Why are the paths you are using to include the connection file, so "wildly" different? `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/db_connection.php`, vs just `db_connection.php`? I'm guessing that one of those probably fails, but you didn't notice due to too lax of an error reporting level maybe? Since this connection is _necessary_ for what you will be doing afterwards, these should rather be `require` than `include` statements to begin with. If _then_ the path was wrong in one instance, you'd get a fatal error in that case.

Comment: Tried both path types, no luck. Even with fixes, no errors logged. Manually accessing `http://localhost:8888/process_submission.php` shows success. However, the form from student_dash.html doesn't seem to submit to process_submission.php. Issue might be form's redirect: `<form id="mainSubmissionForm" action="process_submission.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. Any ideas?